# Post messages to Teams channel using Teams JS

Tags: teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

Is it possible to utilize Teams JS to send messages to the 'Posts' Tab when a Teams App is configured as a Tab within a Teams Channel, without relying on the use of a bot or the Microsoft Graph API?

Something like this

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context) {
    var channelId = context[channelId].Post("This message should appear in the 'Posts' Tab");
});
```

[image]